# Sorting data from Json array using android volley into activity

Tags: java, android, json

Im using volley to get and handle the Json object into the activity 
and here are the classes and the following :

The problem is when im trying to get the Address ,Phones, Emails as sorting for each line from the object it show up like this first it get the address with the first line then it jumps to line 5 to get id then line 8 to get twitterUrl.

[Inside the APP Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhxv9.jpg)

web Service reponse on the postman

```
[
{
"address": "adddress1",
"emails": "ggggdjd@ttttt.com",
"facebookUrl": "ddddd",
"googlePlus": "ddddddd",
"id": 1,
"instagramUrl": "ddddd",
"phones": "0100098763 - 82726353",
"twitterUrl": "ddddd",
"youtubeUrl": "dddd"
}
]
```

Content Volley.java

```
extends BaseVolley {

// base url for srever

String TAG = "sjnsn";
private final String url = url ;

protected enum ActionType implements BaseVolley.ActionType {
    appcontactus
}

public ContentVolley(String TAG, Context context) {
    super(TAG, VolleySingleton.getInstance(context));
}

// method created as an example for post request for a certain api

public void getAboutUs() {
    params = new HashMap<>();
    actionType = ActionType.appcontactus;
    requestAction(Request.Method.GET, url + ((Enum) actionType).name(), true);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute(BaseVolley.ActionType actionType) {
    ActionType action = (ActionType) actionType;
    onPreExecute(action);
}

@Override
protected void getResponseParameters(String response) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    String message = "";
    try {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
        Log.d(TAG, "getResponseParameters: "+response);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        message = jsonObject.optString("msg");
    }
    ActionType action = (ActionType) actionType;

    switch (action) {
        case appcontactus:
            ArrayList<ContactUsItem> contactUsList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String address = jsonObject.optString("address");
                String emails = jsonObject.optString("emails");
                String phones = jsonObject.optString("phones");
                String facebookUrl = jsonObject.optString("facebookUrl");
                String googlePlus = jsonObject.optString("googlePlus");
                String instagramUrl = jsonObject.optString("instagramUrl");
                String twitterUrl = jsonObject.optString("twitterUrl");
                String youtubeUrl = jsonObject.optString("youtubeUrl");
                String id = jsonObject.optString("id");

                ContactUsItem contactUsItem = new ContactUsItem(id, address, emails, phones, facebookUrl,googlePlus,instagramUrl
                ,twitterUrl,youtubeUrl);
                contactUsList.add(contactUsItem);
            }
            onPostExecuteAboutUs(true, message,contactUsList) ;
            break;

    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecuteError(boolean success, String message, BaseVolley.ActionType actionType) {
    ActionType action = (ActionType) actionType;
    switch (action) {
        case appcontactus:
            onPostExecuteAboutUs(false, message, null);
            break;


    }
}


protected abstract void onPreExecute(ActionType actionType);

protected void onPostExecuteAboutUs(boolean success, String message,ArrayList<ContactUsItem> contactUsList) {
}

protected void onPostExecuteappnews(boolean success, String message, Object result) {
}
}
```

AboutUsFragment.java

```
public class AboutusFragment extends Fragment {
private final String TAG = AboutusFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private RelativeLayout relativeLayoutLoading;

private TextView email;
private TextView phone;
private TextView addres;

private ImageView imageViewFacebook, imageViewInstagram, imageViewTwitter;

public AboutusFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_us, container, false);

    relativeLayoutLoading = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutLoading);

    email = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
    phone = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPhone);
    addres = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);

    imageViewFacebook = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFacebook);
    imageViewInstagram = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewInstagram);
    imageViewTwitter = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewTwitter);

    Content content = new Content();
    content.getAboutUs();


    return rootView;
}

private class Content extends ContentVolley {

    public Content() {
        super(TAG, getContext());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(ActionType actionType) {

    }

    protected void onPostExecuteAboutUs(boolean success, String message, ArrayList<ContactUsItem> contactUsList) {

        if (success) {
            for (int i = 0; i < contactUsList.size(); i++) {
                ContactUsItem contactUsItem = contactUsList.get(i);
                email.setText(contactUsItem.getEmail());
                phone.setText(contactUsItem.getPhone());
                addres.setText(contactUsItem.getAddress());
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
}
}
```